# сбивается таймер при перезапуске кода

Tags: node.js, socket.io

есть таймер работающий на сокетах.

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('start', function (data) {
    countdown = 7200;
var t =  setInterval(function() {
  countdown--;
var hours = Math.floor(countdown / 60 /60 );
var minutes = Math.floor(countdown / 60) - (hours * 60);
var seconds = countdown % 60;
let timer =  hours +":"+ minutes +":"+ seconds ;
  io.sockets.emit('timer', { countdown: timer});
}, 1000);
  socket.on('stop', function () {
    clearInterval(t);
})
  });

});
```

работает по назначению, но есть нюанс. Если я  перезапущу сервер nodejs  таймер сбивается.
и плюс к этому если два раза нажму на старт то таймер считает быстрее в два раза соответственно(. Если выношу setInterval  за пределы "start"  то он начинает считать еще до нажатия на кнопку подскажите в каком направлении хотя бы искать проблему.

Comment: Перезапуск на то и перезапуск, чтобы приложение всё забыло и начало с чистого листа. Если вам нужно иное поведение, то сохраняйте значение таймера в постоянной памяти, а не в оперативной. Блокируйте кнопку старт, если она уже нажата.

Comment: @ArchDemon,  а можно чуть подробнее по поводу постоянной памяти и блокировки кнопки?